# INSERT current date and specific time MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Im trying to insert the current date and a specific time into a table this is my query

```
INSERT INTO friday_records(apprentice_name,dt,active) VALUES ('$name','CONCAT(CURDATE(), 10:00:00)',1)
```

and this is the output on my table

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XC6Z3.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quotes:

```
INSERT INTO friday_records(apprentice_name,dt,active) VALUES ('$name',CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 10:00:00'),1);
```

You were quoting the function. You just had to quote the time.